# How to define higher inductive types in Z3

Tags: types, z3, homotopy-type-theory

Higher Inductive Types are very important tools in Homotopy Type Theory.  I am trying to define some kinds of higher inductive types using Z3-SMT-LIB.  One example is the circle, which is freely generated by a point, `base`, and a path, `loop`, from `base`to itself.  I am using the code

```
(declare-datatypes () ((Circle base (loop (Circle Circle)))))
(declare-fun x1 () Circle)
(declare-fun x2 () Circle)
(assert (not (= x1 x2)))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

and the output is

```
sat 
(model 
 (define-fun x2 () Circle (loop base)) 
 (define-fun x1 () Circle base) )
```

The question is: I am really defining the higher inductive type named circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Z3 supports only first-order inductive types. The one you provided is also first-order.